# Problem with message queue creation in RT-POSIX

Tags: c, queue, real-time, rtos

I'm trying to implement a real time program, especially written with RT-POSIX. I ran into a problem creating queues. Basically, I create two queues in the "reference.c" file:

```
mqd_t reference_qd1;
mqd_t reference_qd2;
if ((reference_qd1=mq_open(REFERENCE_QUEUE_NAME1, O_WRONLY))==-1) {
            perror("reference mqopen reference_qd1");
            return -1;
}

if(mq_send(reference_qd1,argv[1],strlen(argv[1])+1,0)==-1) {
    perror("reference send reference_qd1");
    return -1;
}

if (mq_close (reference_qd1) == -1) {
    perror ("reference: mq_close reference_qd1");
    return -1;
}


if ((reference_qd2=mq_open(REFERENCE_QUEUE_NAME2,O_WRONLY))==-1) {
    perror("reference mqopen reference_qd2");
    return -1;
}



if(mq_send(reference_qd2,argv[2],strlen(argv[2])+1,0)==-1) {
    perror("reference send reference_qd2");
    return -1;
}

if (mq_close (reference_qd2) == -1) {
    perror ("reference: mq_close reference_qd2");
    return -1;
}
```

However, when I run the file, only the first queue is created while the second one outputs the creation error message to the terminal.

```
reference mqopen reference_qd2: No such file or directory
```

thanks everyone in advance!